# Create a Handler inside doInBackground

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to create a timer thread that looks at the download buffer periodically and see how many bytes are in a Thread that I created to download the file. Howevere, I always get this message: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

My code:

```
private class DownloadPdfTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

   // ... code 
   try {
            // Create the URL, needs java.net.URL
            URL mUrl;
            mUrl = new URL(params[0]);

            // Variable to measure Latency (until first byte is received)
            long beforeConnect = System.currentTimeMillis();


            // Open connection to the URL
            mConnection = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
            mConnection.connect();

            long afterConnect = System.currentTimeMillis();

            mLatency = afterConnect - beforeConnect;

            // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
            // instead of the file
            if (mConnection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + mConnection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + mConnection.getResponseMessage();
            }

            fileLength = mConnection.getContentLength();

            // Download the file
            is = mConnection.getInputStream();
            final File osFile = new File("sdcard/filename.pdf");
            if (!osFile.exists())
            {
                try
                {
                    osFile.createNewFile();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    return e.toString();
                }
            }

            os = new FileOutputStream(osFile);

            final byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            int count;

            //  Create timer thread to peek buffer and see how many bytes are there
            final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
            Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mThroughputEverySecond += " " + total;
                    // Run timer task every second
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            };

            while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
                // Allow canceling with back button
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    is.close();
                    return null;
                }
                total += count;
                // Publishing the progress
                if (fileLength > 0) { // Only if total length is known
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                }
                os.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // Stop timer task after download is completed
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHandlerTask);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `handler` can be instantiated on any threads but that thread must have a looper object. how to create a looper? call `looper.prepare();`

then you must create your handler and then call `Looper.loop();`

look at this:

```
class LooperThread extends Thread {
  public Handler mHandler;

  public void run() {
      Looper.prepare();

      mHandler = new Handler() {
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

          }
      };

      Looper.loop();

  }
}
```

Ui thread has a looper object so you do not need to call `looper.prepar()` before creating handler on it but for other threads you must do as I coded.

Comment: @Chris Stratton Yes of course but he dose not touch any ui dose he?

Comment: I ended up using:    `//  Create timer thread to peek buffer and see how     many bytes are there
                Timer mTimer = new Timer();
                mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mThroughputEverySecond += " " + total;
                    }
                }, 0, 1000);`  But your answer was the first correct! Thank you very much. Is Timer also a good choice here?

Comment: yes but remember to shut down  `mTimer` at the end because if you do not  it is running till your process is killed.

Answer (score 3):

Try instantiating your handler using `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` instead.